# Mobile Brain-stroke Rehab Game (MediaPipe and Unity): Stuck Connecting Hand Movements to Game Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile-application, mediapipe

We're building a Unity-based mobile game for stroke rehabilitation using the MediaPipeUnity hand tracking plugin. However, we've hit a bit of a wall: while gesture recognition works like a charm (even turning movements into text in the console!), we're struggling to connect that hand data to game objects for actual interaction.

We've tried our best to troubleshoot:

Calibration: We've explored different calibration methods recommended in the plugin documentation and online tutorials.

Plugin Settings: We've tinkered with plugin settings to optimize tracking smoothness and accuracy.

Tutorials: We've searched high and low for relevant tutorials, but unfortunately, most resources we've found focus on desktop applications using OpenCV, MediaPipe, or Python. We haven't found much specific to mobile app development with Unity and MediaPipe hand tracking.

As beginners, we're not deeply familiar with these concepts, and this lack of mobile-specific tutorials makes things even tougher. We'd be incredibly grateful if any experienced folks out there could offer some guidance! Any suggestions, ideas, or even pointers to relevant resources would be hugely appreciated. We successfully integrated the MediaPipe plugin into our Unity project and can convert hand gestures into text in the console.

Thanks in advance for your help! We're really excited about this project and believe it can make a positive impact on stroke rehabilitation. Your insights could be the key to moving forward!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).